# How to return an array of my class from a vc++ function to C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-c++, com, idl

How do I create and return an array of MyClass objects From a IDL Dll (C++ Project) ? 
the Dll will be used in C# projects.

```
//--- in idl file
[id(8)] HRESULT GetTest([out,retval] SAFEARRAY(IMYClass*)* arr_data)

//--- in .h file
STDMETHOD(GetTest)(SAFEARRAY * arr_data);

//--- in .cpp file
STDMETHODIMP CIMY_Interface::GetTest(SAFEARRAY * arr_data)
{
// Code ????
}
```

My problem is the code that should be written in the `GetTest` function

Answer (score 0):

COM allows you to send back and forth marshalled data types.  These are the main core data types such as integer, widestring, boolean etc, other COM objects and if you want you can write marshalling code for your own objects or array.

What you want to do eg. pass an array of your own object via COM is not really feasible.  Here is a number of options

1. Pass a string representation of your array as something like a JSON string which can be encoded and decoded on either side.
2. Wrap your array in a COM object with item get and set methods and counts etc. This way your function can return a COM object and then return items as called for.  This would be slow for use as an array though.
3. Implement as a VariantArray